# Parse text in Lync IM conversation?

Tags: lync-2010, lync

We currently have a block list for Lync 2010 that contains all file extensions because someone at the company accidentally sent a malicious link to someone else. Long story short, none of the developers can send links and management is hesitant to back off the block list.

For them to back off the block list I need to build a lync extension/tool that can be used to parse and validate the url before it's sent to the IM recipient. I've downloaded the Lync 2010 sdk, am well-versed in c# and would like some advice.

Can you recommend how to setup dev environment to build lync extensions?
Can I do this in VS?
Can you point me to an example on how to parse text or links from an IM conversation?

Thanks for your time,
Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use MSPL (Microsoft SIP Processing Language). You can filter messages passing through Front End Server. For more idea read blog of Michael Greenlee on following url:

http://blog.greenl.ee/2011/12/30/modifying-sip-headers-managed-sip-application-api/

Comment: this looks like a lot of heavy lifting but thanks for the info:)